# Sorting is not working on Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to iterate the array value in a table structure where I want to make sorting based on various titles like Name, City etc... I'm not able to sort the data properly. Please guide me on the same. I've tried storing the city names in a separate array and iterating the same array for showing the city name in the UI but it is showing all cities in every line. Please suggest a proper way how to do that.

```js
employees: Array < any > ;
column: string = 'city';
arr: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.allservice.geturl(this.tableurl)
    .subscribe(

      resEmployeeData => {

        this.employees = resEmployeeData.data

        for (let i = 0; i < this.employees.length; i++) {
          this.arr[i].push(this.employees[i].city)
        }
        console.log(this.arr)
      },
    )
  this.sort(this.column);
}

sort(property) {
  console.log(property)
  this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
  this.column = property;
  this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
};
```

```html
<table align="center" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="pointer" (click)="sort(userResponse.firstName)">
        <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'userResponse.firstName', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'userResponse.firstName' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'userResponse.firstName' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i> FIRST NAME </th>
      <th class="pointer" (click)="sort(arr)">
        <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'city', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'city' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'city' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i> CITY </th>
      <th class="pointer" (click)="sort(email)">
        <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'email', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'email' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'email' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i> EMAIL </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }| category: searchText | orderBy: {property: column, direction:direction}">
      <td>{{employee.userResponse.firstName}}</td>
      <td> {{employee.city}}</td>
      <td> {{employee.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you should be creating a custom pipe for your problem

Comment: i am new to angular2 can u please eloborate and tell please

Comment: Is that all your code? Because `this.arr` is undefined, and so is `arr[i]`, so `this.arr[i].push` will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

If your sorting criteria is static you can modify your ngOnInit to something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.allservice.geturl(this.tableurl)
    .subscribe(resEmployeeData => {
        this.employees = resEmployeeData.data

        for (let i = 0; i < this.employees.length; i++) {
          this.arr[i].push(this.employees[i])
        }

        // Because your array is made using the city you don't need to specify anything
        this.arr.sort((elemA, elemB) => {
          return elemA.city - elemB.city;
        });
    });
}
```

In this case `this.arr.sort();` will short alphabetically the array elements (sort method default behavior). If you want to sort by other condition you can pass a function, take a look at the [sort method documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

In your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of arr">
  <td>{{employee.userResponse.firstName}}</td>
  <td> {{employee.city}}</td>
  <td> {{employee.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, now sort is working and I got the array values in arr. How can I display this list in the view. Currently I'm iterating the employee object to display employee.city, how to display arr instead of that

Comment: If you want to display your array of cities, instead of using the employee in the ngFor use the arr array

Comment: But based on city name, the whole table value has to alter right? How can we achieve that? Any working examples please?

Comment: I've updated the response, can you check if it works?

Comment: by updating my code which you have given to me throws an error of "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. "

Comment: That's another error, there's a lot of information about it because it's quite common